# An interesting math problem I created for an old-school RPG game.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The point of this is to try to have the best stats as possible at the beginning of the game and stay at level 1 before doing any quests.

Starting group at creation menu:

```
Stat        Cleric  Sorcerer 1  Sorcerer 2  Sorcerer 3
Might            7           7           7           7
Intellect        9          14          14          14
Personality     14           9           9           9
Endurance       11          11          11          11
Accuracy        11           7           7           7
Speed            7          14          14          14
Luck            14          11          11          11
```

- You have a pool of 50 bonus points to add to any of the values above.
- Default values cannot be subtracted more than by 2 points.  Any subtracted points are added to the bonus points pool.
- A value cannot exceed 25 points during creation.

In game after creation:

- There are wells in the game that can increment a stat (there are no wells for Endurance) by 2 as many times as it can as long as it is under 15. (If it is 14, then it can be incremented to 16 but that's it)
- Those potions below can be created at the beginning of the game. Each unique potion can be used only once on each character.

Potions:

```
Essence of Accuracy     +15 Accuracy,    -5 Luck    
Essence of Endurance    +15 Endurance,   -1 to all other stats  
Essence of Intellect    +15 Intellect,   -5 Might   
Essence of Luck         +15 Luck,        -5 Accuracy    
Essence of Might        +15 Might,       -5 Intellect   
Essence of Personality  +15 Personality, -5 Speed   
Essence of Speed        +15 Speed,       -5 Personality
```

Goal Priorities:

1. Try to max Intellect as much as possible for Sorcerers.
2. Try to max Personality as much as possible for the Cleric.
3. Try to max total stats for all characters.

Comment: You are allowed to use all of the potions once?
Also what is the point of adding two points at a time up to 15? Does this cost only 1 bonus point?

Comment: Yes, you can use all potions once.

Comment: Can potions push stats past the 25-point creation limit?

Comment: So I could use the Accuracy and Luck potions both on one character, yielding gain on both attributes?

Comment: Yeah, I meant the values cannot exceed 25 during creation.

Comment: Display Name - Yeah, if used both, you get +10 for each.

Comment: What does 'stay at level 1' mean?

Comment: If I just level up without maxing stats, I will gain some stats from leveling up, thus missing out some points that I could gain from the wells (which can increment a stat by 2 as long as it is under 15).